# How to get proper backtrace from signal handler of multi threaded process in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals, backtrace

I'm using Linux and I'm trying to get call stack from signal handler with libunwind for debugging purpose. My target application is multi-threaded, and I don't know which thread will generate which signal.
At first I used libunwind to backtrace the call stack in signal handler, but backtraced result was not the call stack of actual thread that generate the signal(result was something like library call stacks or maybe not...).

After some googling I understanded that most signals(except SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGBUS, SIGSEGV) will be send to process, not actual thread which generate the signal.
My question is, Is there any way to backtrace call stack of actual thread which generate signals in multi threaded application??

If there aren't any simple way, I'm also thinking about workarounds like get pid of thread which generate signal(is this possible???) and send another per-thread signal(like SIGFEP or SIGSEGV) to that thread.

Anyone has idea???

Comment: What do you mean by "backtrace" exactly? Signals are not errors. Also depending on signal type received, such as `SIGKILL`, which user code on target process never actually receives on Linux, causes the program to be killed off, without any unwinding, or any other cleanup code running at all. The process is simply cannibalized and that's it. What do you expect to get from cases like that?

Comment: @Kaihaku I cannot list the signals expected to be generated from target application(cause it's not mine), but I can say SIGKILL is not to be concerned. I'm concerning the signals which can be handled by user space handler. As for the meaning of  "backtrace", I just want to get call stack information of the thread which generate signal. For example in multi threaded application, a thread can double free a malloc'ed memory space and SIGABRT will be generated. And I want to know the call stack of the thread which generate SIGABRT for debugging.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.